# Custom Actions - Button Placement Issue

Tags: custom-actions

This is probably something simple that just has me stumped... I was able to successfully add a print button to my DispForm ribbon, but I am struggling to move it below the Alert Me button. Every time I add it, it goes next to the other Actions.

[image]

I am using SharePoint Designer 2010 for the Custom Action. The only working ribbon location I can find is **Ribbon.ListForm.Display.Actions.Controls._children**, which puts it next to everything.

Comment: Can you show us where it's putting the custom action in a screenshot?

Comment: I can't add a new screen shot of it at the moment. Basically it is doing exactly what Edit Item is in "Manage". Going to the left of the 16x16 icons and pushing them to the right.

Comment: The ID for Workflows is Ribbon.ListForm.Display.Actions-LargeMedium-1-1. I attempted to put in Ribbon.ListForm.Display.Actions-LargeMedium-1-2 for the Print button, but nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

You are targeting the correct location.  You just need to experiment with the Sequence attribute on your button.  That is what determines the order in which to display items within a group.  The lower the Sequence, the further top-left the item will display.

Comment: No luck with different Sequences. Upon checking the code in Firebug it is putting my new button in Ribbon.ListForm.Display.Actions-LargeMedium-0, meanwhile the OOTB buttons are put into Ribbon.ListForm.Display.Actions-LargeMedium-1.